# Why does sliding window example show windows even though there is no event occurence?

Tags: azure, sliding-window

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-streaming#sliding-window

> Sliding windows, unlike tumbling or hopping windows, calculate the
> aggregation only for points in time when the content of the window
> actually changes. When an event enters or exits the window, the
> aggregation is calculated. So, every window has at least one event.
> Similar to hopping windows, events can belong to more than one sliding
> window.

Assuming the window duration is 10, then my understanding is that the window covers 10 seconds prior to (and including the current event). So in the below diagram - the window number (assuming numbering starts from top to bottom) 1, 2, 3 are correct because it goes 10 seconds behind (and including) the event occurrence. And also number 6 is correct.

What is the reasoning for window numbers 4, 5 & 7?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The window content changed.

> when the content of the window actually changes

For example window 3 had 1,5, 7 and 9.
Then 1 fell out, leaving 5, 7 and 9.
Those are in window 4.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to make a window for only 10 seconds behind (and including) the event occurrence?

Comment: You can think of the sliding window like this. The events are points on a line. The window is a rectangle that you slide forward on that line. Now whenever an event enters or exits that window, trigger the window. So if an event entered the window, it would include the 10 seconds before that. However if an event exited the window, the window includes the events 10 seconds after that event.

Comment: Sliding window is used to answer questions like "Is there ever a 10 second period of events where this is true?" Hopping and tumbling windows can skip certain combinations of events so would not be able to answer these questions. These window types are exactly the same in Azure Stream Analytics btw, that documentation can be helpful too.

Comment: Can you please explain me how the windows 4, 5 & 7 appear?

Comment: 4: event 1 drops out, 5: event 5 drops out, 7: event 8 drops out

Comment: Event 5 is on 12th second (window 2), so how come it dropped out at 14th second (window 5)?